# Using "void" type as a parameterized type in Go generics (version 1.18) or above

Tags: go, generics, void

Go introduced generics in [version 1.18](https://go.dev/blog/go1.18beta1). I just downloaded the [latest beta version](https://go.dev/blog/go1.18beta2) to test this major new feature.

Consider the code below:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func Demo1(n int) int {
    return n
}

func Demo2(n int) {
    fmt.Println(n)
}

func Call[T1, T2 any](fn func(T1) T2, param T1) {
    fn(param)
}

func main() {
    // Okay
    Call(Demo1, 1)
    // type func(n int) of Demo2 does not match
    // inferred type func(int) T2 for func(T1) T2
    Call(Demo2, 2)
}
```

The function `Call` accepts a function `fn` as a parameter, and calls it with the parameter `param`. The first call to `Call` is fine, the inferred type is `int` for both `T1` and `T2`. However, the second call failed to compile.

I know I can always write an adapter to wrap `Demo2`:

```golang
wrapped := func(n int) int {
    Demo2(n)
    return -1
}
Call(wrapped, 2)
```

But that hurts performance and defeat the purpose of my current project.

Do you have any ideas to solve the problem? Or shall I fire a bug report?

Thanks!

---

### Edit 1 (Background):

I am updating a benchmarking library I wrote 6 years ago to use generics. It targets to provide carefully written benchmark functions so that the benchmark results are more consistent than writing custom benchmarks independently.

For example, if a user wants to benchmark his function `Sum` of signature `func(int) int`, with the parameter values between `0` and `10`, he can write this:

```golang
func BenchmarkSum(b *testing.B) {
    butils.BenchmarkFnIntRetInt(b, Sum, butils.UniformDistribution(0, 10))
}
```

`BenchmarkFnIntRetInt` could be used to benchmark other `func(int) int` functions. The benchmark results would be more consistent than writing a separate routine, say `BenchmarkProduct` to benchmark the `Product` function. Since the grounds are the same, the benchmark results would be more consistent when comparing implementations by different authors.

In my library, the function signatures look like this:

```golang
func UniformDistribution(min, max int) func() int {
    // ...
}

func BenchmarkFnIntRetInt(
    b *testing.B,
    target func(int) int,
    paramGen func() int,
) {
    // ...
}
```

Since Go has generics now, I could get rid of most of the redundant combinations (a.k.a. overloads, like one for `func(int) int`, and another for `func(int) string`, and yet another for `func(int) bool`), and replace them by generics instead. I hope the users can get rid of the overloads and just write:

```golang
func BenchmarkSum(b *testing.B) {
    butils.BenchmarkGeneric(b, Sum, butils.UniformDistribution(0, 10))
}
```

The problem of [icza's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71038560/142239) of writing one version for "non-void", and another for "void" is that there are a lot of higher order functions in my library. The number of versions I need to write grows exponentially as the number of function parameters grows.

For example, if I have `fn1` and `fn2`, then 4 versions are needed; If I have `fn1`, `fn2` and `fn3`, then 8 versions are needed; and so on.

Comment: This isn't a bug. You simply cannot use a function that doesn't return a value as a function that returns something, generic or not.

Comment: This is normal, pre-generics behaviour of Go.

Comment: @Peter No. As far as I know, the same could be done in at least C++, Java, Scala, and Haskell. They have a type for "nothing", like `void`, `Nothing`, `()`, or similar.

Comment: Peter is not talking about Scala or C++ but Go which this question is about.

Comment: @Volker Yes, I understand. My point is, since generics is a new feature of Go, why couldn't it make it deal with that. As in the comments I wrote under izca's answer, the compiler could be smarter and automatically treat `Call` as `CallNoResult`, then the problem is solved. Although Go does not have a `void` type, in `Call`, the return result of `fn` is thrown away, so no variable of type `void` is ever created.

Please kindly refer to "Edit 1" of my question on why I need that. Thanks! 

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug. There is no `void` type in Go.

Your `Call()` function requires an argument of function type that must have a result parameter. `Demo2()` does not have any. It does not qualify for the first argument to `Call()` no matter what types are used to instantiate the parameterized `Call()` function.

You can't describe functions with and without result types with a single type, not even with type parameters.

You must use 2 `Call()` functions, e.g.:

```
func Call[T1, T2 any](fn func(T1) T2, param T1) {
    fn(param)
}

func CallNoResult[T any](fn func(T), param T) {
    fn(param)
}
```

And using them (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/_oh5uKHGT-j?v=gotip)):

```
Call(Demo1, 1)
CallNoResult(Demo2, 2)
```

If you need to handle all function types, you should use reflection. Here's the essence of it (type and parameter checks omitted):

```
func Call(f interface{}, params ...interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(f)

    vparams := make([]reflect.Value, len(params))
    for i, p := range params {
        vparams[i] = reflect.ValueOf(p)
    }
    v.Call(vparams)
}
```

Testing it:

```
func Demo1(n int) int {
    fmt.Println("Demo1", n)
    return n
}

func Demo2(n int) {
    fmt.Println("Demo2", n)
}

func main() {
    Call(Demo1, 1)
    Call(Demo2, 2)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/H0pfKGTgtMh)):

```
Demo1 1
Demo2 2
```

Comment: Hi, @izca. Thank you for answering my question (as always). I know that Go does not have a `void` type, and I understand that your solution is valid.

Since my current project is a benchmarking library (providing carefully written benchmark functions, so that the benchmark results are more consistent across implementations), that means there will be a lot of higher order functions like `Call` above. The number of functions I need to write grows exponentially as the number of parameters grows. For example, if I have `fn1`, `fn2`, and `fn3`, then I need 8 functions.

Comment: Please note that `T2` is in fact not used in the implementation of `Call`, which means there is no variable of the non-existent type `void`, so it does not violate the original Go language. Well, but I know the function signature does not allow this to happen at the first place. Perhaps, as a suggestion to a later version of Go, the compiler can treat `Call` as `CallNoResult` if it found that the return type is "nothing"?

Comment: Originally I wrote this without generics, and that was a mess. I need to write a function for every combination of the types. After 6 years, I come back to my project now and hope that generics could tidy up my library, but I found that "nothing" is still a problem.

Thanks for answering anyway! 

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- If you need to handle all function types, you should use reflection.

Comment: Yeah, I could use `reflect`, but since it is a benchmarking library, the reflection calls themselves may defeat the purpose of the benchmarks, since they may dominate the execution time in the benchmark results.

Comment: Of course I could measure how long it takes to just run the benchmark routines themselves, by creating an empty implementation of the target routine as a "control" (say, creating an empty implementation of `func(int) int` on the fly with `reflect`, I am not even sure if that is possible, but let's assume it is), and subtract the time taken by it. This seems to be the only way to do this for now. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it would be so much more practical if it the return type worked nicely with generics...